# Internet Explorer 8+ - New Session per tab

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, session, tabs

It is obvious that IE8 has limitations with new sessions per tab. By design IE8+ does not allow new sessions per tab automatically. I understand why it is designed this way, but I think Microsoft's IE team overlooked all situations for users/sessions.

There is an IE8 menu option "File -> New Session" which creates the functionality which I need.

Unfortunately, my users cannot be trained to use "File -> New Session". I must try to accomplish this in code, programmatically.

My question is...What is "File -> New Session" doing under the covers? I need to replicate this menu functionality but cannot find any good examples on how to do it, without re-inventing the wheel. Obviously IE8 can create new sessions (per tab) easily, but how in code???

I do not want to change the web.config or put GUID's in my Query String, as that is not acceptable for our users, so please do not suggest doing that.

Any help is appreciated.

** EDIT: my scenario is that our users login to our web system, make some edits, then open a new tab to login as a different user. The new login user receives Session data from the previous user. I want to avoid sharing Session data between tabs. If users use "File -> New Session" it works, but we cannot rely on that. I want to write the code to replicate that menu functionality in our app.

Comment: Downvoting leditimate questions is really lame. How do you expect new users to ever get enough points to upvote?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET session the same in all tabs because using a HTTP Cookie. Cookie shared for all browser tabs. If you don't like cookieless session with a URL parameters you can use ajax-calls and look for JavaScript **window.name** property. It's property is unique for all tabs (windows) and you can set you own value.

Example of this approach:
[Javascript session-variables without cookies](http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/javascript-session-variables-without-cookies/)

Comment: No it's the same session because of the IE process thread. I would like to see examples of code. Specifically how "File -> New Session" from the menu works.

Comment: You make a ASP.NET website or some IE extension?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET website and the users use IE8. The session is shared between tabs because of IE's process thread. It's well documented on the web. My goal is to replicate the menu option "File -> New Session" without any javascript or fancy hacks.

Answer (score 0):

In common it's a some dirty hack, but can work in your case.

```
<script language="javascript">
var a = external.menuArguments;
if(a && (a = a.event) && (a = a.srcElement) && (a = a.href))
{
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore\" -nomerge \"" + a + "\"");
}
</script>
```

http://waissguy.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/how-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-session-with-ie8/

Comment: THe users are not opening tabs programmatically. They are opening new tabs via the IE menu. This will not work. I need the code that creates a new session when a tab is created. Not Shell code to invoke a browser. I need to place the "new session" code in my login routines.

Comment: I would like to see examples of code. Specifically how "File -> New Session" from the menu works.